# Make dropdown menu in IOS app with swift

Tags: ios, swift

How can I make a drop down menu in my swift IOS app that has different options that the user can select, whatever they select displays in a label above the menu. Example: drop down menu to select age in an app. Or like the select size and quantity option in the following link http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pd/roshe-run-shoe/pid-463712/pgid-943980.

Please let me know if you can help me accomplish this, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I achieved similar feature on Objective-C, hope the same concept can be applied on swift.

I actually subclass a UITableView with some customized functions and variables, then instantiate the class with desired coordination and dimension and use UITableViewDelegate methods to trigger the events needed.